# fontawesome icon not rendering the same in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, compatibility, font-awesome

In Chrome/Safari my icon within a bootstrap button looks fine:

[image: chome icon]

But in Firefox, the icon drops down a line:

[image: firefox icon]

I have the fontawesome icon floated right within the `<button>`.

```
<!--html-->
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Cached logs<i class="fa fa-money"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Logs on mount<i class="fa fa-database"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--style-->
i.fa {
float: right;
top: 2px;
position: relative;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.glyphicon, i.fa {
color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
top: 1px;
}
```

How can I make the Firefox version one-line like the Chrome?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/satoxavapo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the icon to the left of the text. I'm not sure of the underlying cause of it not being consistent how you've got it - but this does make both browsers render it consistently.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Logs on mount</button>
```

Instead of

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Logs on mount<i class="fa fa-database"></i></button>
```

Comment: I would really love to know how this even works. I never would have thought to try that! Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. At a guess, I'd say firefox is rendering the text as a block level element inside the button for some strange reason. Couldn't see why when I tried debugging. Since floated elements are taken out of flow, putting it before the text made sense - so I tested it and it worked :) Would love to hear back about this if anyone can explain.